# Is this fair to ask or say hi hello to CEO?

Tags: professionalism, software-industry, communication, middle-east

Actually I am working in Multi-National company. Our head office is in another city and we are few members team in another city. All our upper management is not in our city.

I am hired by company CEO and did very cooperate with me when I was hired. Since they are in another city that's why usually they come after two or three months in our office for two or three days.

So is this fair to ask "How are you?" or "Hi n Hello" something like that after 4 to 5 weeks.

Kindly guide me about it, thank you so much.

Answer (score 11):

It would seem strange for you to knock on the door of their office and intrude if they're working.

However, it should be fine to say "Hello" or "Good morning" if you happen to pass in a corridor.  He might well remember you and you can then thank them for hiring you if the conversation allows.

Don't expect that they'll remember you (and don't be offended if they don't) - these people meet a lot of people in their day-to-day work.

Comment: It's not only fine but I'd actually expect a greeting from employees if they pass the CEO in a corridor.

Answer (score 4):

If you have been introduced to any worker, not just the CEO, it's perfectly fine to say hi, and would be considered rude in some circumstances not to. But what matters greatly is the context, and indeed the manner in-which you communicate.

You can't walk into a meeting, look across the room and greet the CEO.

You also should refrain from seeking them out, just to say hi. They will be busy.

Also, keep in mind, that brown-nosers are spotted a mile away. Don't be that guy.

If you bump into them in the hallway, you should certainly feel free to say hi. If they are speaking with a client or customer, or with people you are not familiar with, you should probably refrain from making the first move. It's better just to do a small nod if you both make eye contact.

Also, senior management, and even interviewers often meet hundreds of people a year, and it can be hard to keep track of them all. So don't worry if they don't remember you.

You will get a feel for the workplace culture at your place. At the places I've worked at for example, the CEOs will happily sit down for lunch with random workers (after being invited) and have a chat over lunch. (And these are companies with over 1000 workers). But equally, there may be places where the CEOs never do this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but with a clear intent and very briefly.

**The most important resource for higher ups in most companies is their time, and they tend to value it, and value people who respect it. They do not have much for office chit chat.**

So, if after 4-5 weeks, you want to "touch bases", you can send something along the lines of

> Dear Boss,
>
> I Hope you are all right,
> I myself have found my place, and enjoy working here at ACME company, and I wanted to thank you for the opportunity once again.
>
> Looking forward to seeing you on *next meeting*
>
> All the best,
>
> Imran

This message has a purpose (it is a thank you note and an update on how you fit in your new job), is short and fills your need for some contact.

But as a rule of thumb, i tend to limit communication with higher ups to what is strictly necessary.